# Linear Regression updation of bias term and coefficient

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

In Linear Regression we want to minimise the cost function(S) (i.e., Mean Square Error)

Suppose for a dataset having only one feature and a target.

We use a regression line initially as y = α + β*x   where α is bias and β is the coefficient of x.

By using δS/δα = 0, δS/δβ = 0 we can directly derive the formula for α,β as

β = (∑(xi-x̅)*(yi-y̅) )/(∑(xi-x̅)^2) where x̅,y̅ are means of x,y

α = y̅ - β*x̅

So as we can get α,β directly for the best fit curve,why we need to use learning the α,β by iterations?

Comment: Check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) which talks a bit about computations. For your problem, there are closed-form solutions and iterative-procedures (while some more complex problems like l1-regularization has no closed-form). Actually there are many many algorithms and not all iterative-procedures need a learning-rate (sometimes line-search will take care of that). Some are guaranteed to give you an optimal solution, some are not. For the closed-form solutions, the real inverse is never used, but the pseudoinverse, which is much more stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need iteration or gradient descent on a simple linear regression with only one (or a few) features. You can just use the [normal equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html).  This, however, doesn't scale when you have many features because finding the inverse of a large matrix is expensive. It's not uncommon in machine learning to have problems with hundreds (or even thousands) of features.